# Create data template using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, templates, sql-server-2000

By using SQL Server 2000, I want to create a output data template as shown below using data's in table1 and table2

**Output Data_Template**

```
Unit1   | Sale_value_1  | Sale_value_2|
-------------------------------------------    
chart1  | 25             |12|
chart2  | 30             |0|
chart3  | 56             |0|
chart4  | 41             |98|
```

**Table1**

```
Date        |Unit1  |Sale_value_1|
------------------------------------    
2/11/2014   |chart1 |25|
2/11/2014   |chart2 |30|
2/11/2014   |chart3 |56|
2/11/2014   |chart4 |41|
```

**Table2**

```
Date        |Unit1  |Sale_value_2|
-----------------------------------    
2/11/2014   |chart1 |12|
2/11/2014   |chart2 |0|
2/11/2014   |chart3 |0|
2/11/2014   |chart4 |98|
```

Comment: As a side note, your "technical term" of *output data template* does not make any sense in the vernacular.  I believe it would be clearer if you had said I want to create an output result set or output table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0fd1/1/0) demonstrates the below query:

```
SELECT t1.Unit1, t1.Sale_value_1, t2.Sale_value_2 
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Unit1 = t2.Unit1
```